# React Native call async function using this.props inside .then()

Tags: firebase, react-native, asynchronous

Hello i am trying to execute a login props after the user get logged in firebase, with the then() i have the user variable that i can use but i can't use the function _login in here :

```
onClickLogin = async () => {
  if (this.state.email && this.state.password) {
    firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(function (user) {
      this._login(user)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      if (error) {
        alert(error)
      }
    })

  } else {
    alert('Veuillez remplir tous les champs')
  }
}
```

_login function :

```
_login = async (user) => {
  this.props.screenProps.isLoggedIn();
  AsyncStorage.setItem('user', user.user.uid);
  AsyncStorage.setItem('loggedInStatus', 'loggedIn');
}
```

what should i do ?

Comment: what do you mean you cannot use the `_login` function? Do you have an error?

Comment: Yes i am getting this._login is undefined

Comment: as a side note, you don't need the `async` keyword unless you use `await`  inside the function

Comment: Yes i just forgot to put it back before AsyncStorage calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this function:

```js
onClickLogin = async () => {
  if (this.state.email && this.state.password) {
    firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(function (user) {
      this._login(user)
    }.bind(this)) // bind here
    .catch(function(error) {
      if (error) {
        alert(error)
      }
    }.bind(this)); // bind here

  } else {
    alert('Veuillez remplir tous les champs')
  }
}
```

Why these 2 binds?

This wasn't working because `"this"` is different inside of axios. `"this"` inside axios refers to the axios object, not your react component. So, you can solve this with `.bind`.

Comment: Great! If you can, please mark as solved. I edited the answer adding the why i used bind.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer said. `this` inside of the callback is bound to your `firebase` context

For `this` to be bound to your class you can use the [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) that will bind `this` inside of the `then` callback to `this` passed as the argument to the `bind` function, which is bound to your class

To avoid `this` being bound to the `firebase` context inside of the `then` callback you could also use an arrow function

```
.then((user) => {
  this._login(user)
})
```